# Window phone 7 SDK to Window phone 8 SDK

Tags: windows-phone-7

I made a simple application using window phone 7 SDK and in which I implemented a mail task using EmailComposeTask. When I was testing the application to send a mail it said me to set account and you cannot send mail. I have found a solution that I have to install window phone 8 sdk to check this mail functionality. So question If I install window phone 8 SDK , then My other code will work properly or not? What the other thing I have to care to run my current application.

Thanks,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a WP app is developed targeting WP 7.1, then it doesn't matter whether you are running it in WP 7 sdk or WP8 sdk. So, you code works the same even if you run in WP8 sdk.

Btw, if you cannot check email task in the WP7 emulator, you can test that in a device. Ofcourse, it needs a developer account to do so.

Also, WP8 Emulator works only in a Windows 8 Pro version. Because it needs the Hyper-V. And your hardware also should support that.

Good luck !!